# React Bootstrap Images not pulling images from the local product.js file

Tags: react-bootstrap

**here in the Image the src={product.image} in not pulling any images from my product.js local arrays of objects**
but its working on the other pages and also works if put the direct path as src="../images/vibestick.jpg"

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap' 
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import products from '../product'

const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {

    const product = products.find( (p) => p._id ===  match.params.id )

    return (
        <>
            <Link className="btn btn-light my-3" to="/home">
                Go Back
            </Link>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}>
                    <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <ListGroup variant="flush" >
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

Comment: Can you add the `product` object to see what the content looks like?

Comment: Write a `{JSON.stringify(product)}` just above the image and see the value you get.